# Dynamically access the control name in code behinde

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a series of divs which I want to show/hide depending on a the logged in user's userGroup.

```
<div id="divUserGroup1" runat="server" visible ="false"> 
</div>
<div id="divUserGroup2" runat="server" visible ="false"> 
</div>
<div id="divUserGroup3" runat="server" visible ="false"> 
</div>
```

I use the following to retreive the usergroup.

```
userGroup = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userGroup"]);
```

Is there a better way then doing the following.

```
if (userGroup == 1)
{
     divUserGroup1.Visible = true;
}
else if (userGroup == 2)
{
     divUserGroup2.Visible = true;
}
```

I was thinking some sort of divUsergroup" + userGroup + ".Visible = True

But I can't get anything to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Page.FindControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx) to find a control by its name:

```
Control c = this.FindControl("divUsergroup" + userGroup);

if (c != null) // it exists?
{
    c.Visible = true;
}
```

(Note that this only finds top level controls)

Comment: I'm getting this error c.Visible = 'c.Visible' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'. I tried changing the "divUsergroup" to match the case of my div too.

Comment: This is the way to do it. If your code doesn't work, please post your code.